# Pushing nuget symbol packages to Artifactory removes ".symbols." from the package name and overwrites the regular package

Tags: nuget, artifactory, debug-symbols, symbol-server

I am pushing Nuget packages (`.nupkg`) and their associated symbol packages (`.symbols.nupkg`) to Artifactory with `dotnet nuget push`. However, in every way I have tried to do it, the `.symbols` part of the package name is removed, and the original, non-symbols package gets overwritten. Even if I push only the symbols package, it gets renamed.

In addition, it is my understanding that Artifactory is supposed to parse the `.pdb` file and add data under `.symbols/` in the root of the repo. The repo has previously pushed packages (from a long time ago) that have both the correct file names and the correct entries under `.symbols/`. However, I am pushing from a new script.

I have tried pushing the packages as part of a single operation with `--symbol-source`, which seems to put the incorrectly named symbols package in *both* places. I have tried pushing regular and symbols packages in separate operations to completely separate repos. I have tried using the newer `.snupkg` format. I have tried pushing with vanilla `nuget` instead of `dotnet nuget`. In all cases I still wind up with a symbols package with no `.symbols.` in the name, and no parsed `.pdb` data in the `.symbols/` directory.

The environment where this script runs is the stock `dotnet:7.0` container provided by Microsoft, which is based on Debian 10.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the following property was set to True:
artifactory.nuget.symbol.server.support.enabled

If it was set, please share your Artifactory version and your uploading script.

Comment: Artifactory version is `7.47.15`. I don't see any properties set anywhere, though several repos have Symbols already, so some part of that must be working.